# How to get the Property value using string Variable?

Tags: c#, .net, messagebox

```
string str = "txtRate.Text";
MessageBox.Show(str);
```

how to get the value entered in `txtRate` text box in C#.net using above code?

Comment: remove the quotes around `txtRate.Text` !!!

Answer (score 2):

You may try `messageBox.show(txtRate.Text);`

Comment: pls add little more desc for op to understand

Comment: txtRate.Text will give you value entered in txtRate so you don't need to use str here you can directly print the value of txtRate in that messageBox

Comment: Please add in your answer i know what your are talking about this is for patrik not me

Comment: but why do you want to put it in string? you may try this with object object obj=txtRate; messageBox.show(((TextBox)obj).Text) ;

Answer (score 1):

Note: if you are trying to get the value based on something someone types in a TextBox this answer applies:

It is not entirely possible what you ask but you can get close:

```
FieldInfo field = this.GetType().GetField("txtRate"
                     BindingFlags.NonPublic | 
                     BindingFlags.Instance);
PropertyInfo property = field.FieldType.GetProperty("Text");

object val = property.GetValue(field.GetValue(this));
```

Comment: you are making it complicated!

Comment: @Neel: depends on the question. Since OP is specifically asking how to get the property value I thought this might just be a difficult question which wasn't written very clearly.

Comment: yes I agree with you actually OP havnt asked the clear question what he exatly wants..that is the reason of confusion.

Comment: I think it's what the op is asking for, a way to retrieve a value from member names contained in string.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply try the below code.

```
string str = txtRate.Text; 
    MessageBox.Show(str);
```

or simply

```
MessageBox.Show(txtRate.Text);
```